# write code as less as possible to change div position at a complex website

Tags: jquery, html, css

My website project is coming finish, but my client want to change a small div position. If follow the normal way, e.g, set up div position and float attributes, I have to change a lots code, it is not valuable. So I want to write code as less as possible.

In order to let you guys understand my situation as well, I list the example code and requirements. Please forgive me can't put all code there, because it is so much.

Example code:

```
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div id="hello">Hello word
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

- Requirement 1: can't change html code, can't use/change .css file,
  seems just can use javascript, but if there is another way, is welcome.
- Requirement 2: write code as less as possible.
- Requirement 3: use jquery should be best
- Requirement 4:can't use position and  float attributes

Comment: what's exactly your question? What you need to achieve with the code above?

Comment: Where is your try? Where is your code? Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: Change the CSS. Using JS solely for UI purposes is just lazy.

Comment: I don't know how to describe better, but seems Billy & Sandeeproop can understand my question and they gave the answers. I try their answers, work! Thanks your guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use offset function like below:

```
$("#hello").offset({ top: newhellodivtop , left: newhellodivleft });
```

Note: make sure this code is executed follow all code that related to "hello" div

Comment: Wow! it is awesome, just post my question 1 minute, immediately get 27 times viewed and 1 answer. Thank you guys. Seems Billy's answer met my requirements, any other answers? I will wait 1 hour, if no other better answer, I will choose Billy's answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you use margin? If yes

```
$("#hello").css("margin","0px 10px 0px 20px");
```

Comment: Seems good, let me try, thanks